# Remove object from a list of objects in python

Tags: python, list, object

In Python, how can I remove an object from a list of objects? Like this:

```
x = object()
y = object()
array = [x, y]
# Remove x
```

I've tried `array.remove()` but it only works with a value, not a specific location in the array. I need to be able to delete the object by addressing its position (`remove array[0]`).

Comment: The code comment in your post _is_ the answer: it's just `array.remove(x)`, you don't need its position at all. After all, how would you even know `x` is in position 0 without knowing `x`?

Answer (score 87):

There are various ways to delete an object from a list:

```
my_list = [1,2,4,6,7]

del my_list[1] # Removes index 1 from the list
print my_list # [1,4,6,7]
my_list.remove(4) # Removes the integer 4 from the list, not the index 4
print my_list # [1,6,7]
my_list.pop(2) # Removes index 2 from the list
```

In your case the appropriate method to use is `pop`, because it takes the index to be removed:

```
x = object()
y = object()
array = [x, y]
array.pop(0)
# Using the del statement
del array[0]
```

Comment: You should update the second part of your answer and have him use .pop(0) since he specifically asks about removing by position.

Comment: When using `del array[0]` is removed` from the list but `x` itself still exists. Is there a method to remove `x` simultaneously (for example by deleting `x` by its pointer)?

Answer (score 7):

```
del array[0]
```

where `0` is the index of the object in the [list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) (there is no array in python)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove multiple object from a list. There are various ways to delete an object from a list

Try this code. a is list with all object, b is list object you want to remove.

example :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,3]

for i in b:
   if i in a:
      a.remove(i)

print(a)
```

the output is `[1,4,5,6]`
I hope, it will work for you

Comment: What is `link` ?

Comment: And `else: pass` is redundant.

Comment: @Rafael i'm sorry, variable "link" in there is my mistake. I just to correct it. check = i in a.

Comment: yes, no problem using else: pass or no. Thank you for your idea. @Rafael

Answer (score 6):

You could try this to dynamically remove an object from an array without looping through it? Where e and t are just random objects.

```
>>> e = {'b':1, 'w': 2}
>>> t = {'b':1, 'w': 3}
>>> p = [e,t]
>>> p
[{'b': 1, 'w': 2}, {'b': 1, 'w': 3}]
>>>
>>> p.pop(p.index({'b':1, 'w': 3}))
{'b': 1, 'w': 3}
>>> p
[{'b': 1, 'w': 2}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a string from an array like this:

```
array = ["Bob", "Same"]
array.remove("Bob")
```

Answer (score 2):

If we have an object `x` (e.g. an instance of some class `X`) that's in a list of other objects of the same type, we can simply directly remove it using `list.remove()`, provided the class has `__eq__` properly implemented (this is already the case for built-in object types, but for custom classes always remember to implement the eq dunder function):

```
class X():
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.a = value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not hasattr(other, 'a'):
           return False
        return self.a == other.a

x = X(4)
y = X(10)
z = X(9)

my_list = [x,y,z]
print([e.a for e in a])
# prints [4, 10, 9]

my_list.remove(x)

print([e.a for e in a])
# prints [10, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna remove the last one just do `your_list.pop(-1)`
if you wanna remove the first one `your_list.pop(0)` or any index you wish to remove

Answer (score 0):

If you know the array location you can can pass it into itself. If you are removing multiple items I suggest you remove them in reverse order.

```
#Setup array
array = [55,126,555,2,36]
#Remove 55 which is in position 0
array.remove(array[0])
```