# Remove and destroy object in a list

Tags: list, object, python-2.7, destroy

Extending a little on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754729/remove-object-from-array-of-objects-in-python).  Removing an object from a Python list is easy enough, but I'm going to have a "busy" list -- frequent removals and frequent additions -- so I want to guard against memory leaks.

1. Will just removing the object from the list destroy the object?  (I'm assuming No.)
2. If my assumption is correct, then how can I remove it from the list **and** destroy it at the same time?

If it matters, the objects in question are instances of a class that I wrote.  I plan on creating the objects "live" each time I need to insert a new one, e.g.

```
myList.insert(index,myClass(constructorParm1,constructorParm2))
```

So when I later need to delete some of the instances created that way, I want to be sure they're not just gone from the list, but gone period.

Comment: If there are no more references to an object (in cPython, at least), it will be destroyed.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.x.  If it does the same, then great.

Comment: @JDM: Python 2.7 is a cPython version. It does just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cPython, objects are *automatically* destroyed when their reference count drops to 0.

If you delete a entry from your list, the reference count for the object in question is decremented. You do not need to do anything special to have it destroyed, nor should you try to. If any other reference to the object still exists, then destroying the object would break the other reference.

If you want to hold references to an object that do *not* stop the object from being garbage collected, use a [`weakref`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) reference instead.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.  Does it do the same?  If so, then great, no problem.

Comment: Python 2.7 is a cPython version, so yes it does. We are specifying this a cPython as opposed to Jython, IronPython or PyPy, which handle object lifetimes differently.

Comment: "auto-reaped"? Is that a weird way of spelling - "garbage collected"? ;)

Comment: @JonClements: I suppose it is; replaced.