# How can I remove the first element of a xarray.DataArray?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a xarray.DataArray:

```
array([  5.437614e+01,   2.090367e+02,   3.687384e+02, ...,   5.121467e-02,
         5.116013e-02,   5.110552e-02])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1999-12-01 2010-06-01T06:00:00 ...
```

I found several answers for lists, but I am not able to do it for an array.

## Tried

```
a1.pop[0]

AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Comment: This kind of array? https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html If so: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.pop

Comment: @FelixKling An xarray.DataArray to be more precise.

Comment: I had tried it. Please see edit.

Comment: Well, `xarray.DataArray` is not what I linked to so you cannot expect that API to work.   That's why I asked you to clarify what you are using.

Comment: Anyway, it should have been `a1.pop(0)`. I suspect `a1 = a1[1:]` will work.

Comment: Please provide the *full* [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! It does....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `a1 = a1[1:]` because that should work perfectly

Comment: Tried with python3 and xarray.DataArray and indeed **it does work**

Answer (score 0):

Try other brackets (the round ones):

```
a1.pop(0)
```

Edit: I found the second answer very useful, but it's about list since there are no arrays in Python?

[Remove object from a list of objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754729/remove-object-from-a-list-of-objects-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: That won't work either. `pop` doesn't exist: `AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'pop'`

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question, so no. I just pointed out that your answer cannot work.

Comment: @Chipsvernichter the question isn't *about `list` objects*, it is about `xarray.DataArray` objects.